# Taking benefit of a new Angular release candidate?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-seed

I for one is pretty exited every time Angular(two) comes out with a new version. They just released rc3 last night and i figured - Let's try it out.

Creating a new angular 2 project is not as easy as just downloading a zip and link it in your entry page, especially if you want to write it in TypeScript. You soon find out that there are several different options though. They kinda all boil down to using `npm` and configuring a `package.json` file.

So how do you create a working package.json file? Well they released a CLI tool (https://cli.angular.io/) to help you create a new project - and boy, do i love that! I just did a fresh install of the CLI and created a project.

These are the dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
```

As you can see, all the @angular (except router) versions point to rc.1 and not the newest rc.3. Why is that? I guess i could manually change all the rc.1 to rc.3 but would that just work and what about the router. I know from the release notes (http://angularjs.blogspot.dk/2016/06/rc3-now-available.html) that specific changes was made to that.

At this point, manually changing the dependencies would be kinda like poking a stick in your brain and twirl it around. It might help, but it probably would just mess it up.

---

**TL;DR:**
How do you start using this new release candidate? How are we supposed to test it? Wouldn't a short list of (new) dependencies be required for everybody to start testing? It it just a teaser (the new rc3) and are we ment to wait for the CLI (or perhaps seed project) to update before we can actually use it?

Comment: the seed project was updated to the new rc3

Comment: @AngJobs ok thanks. Guess perhaps it's just the CLI that is being slow - it's two rc's behind now...

Comment: I actually found this example package.json file and it seems to be updated: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html

Comment: This is one commit for rc3 update https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/commit/7265c6acfbe6a29f71c035a9f3a4a10cf78f418c

Comment: Ok that seem pretty close to what i'd expect to see. Would be nice if they listed the changes along with the changelog so one wouldn't have to keep an eye on the seed...

Comment: New releases can take some time... the CLI's source code is currently using RC2 and a pull request to update to RC3 has been submitted (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1161)

Comment: @Brocco I uninstalled the cli, did a cache clear and reinstalled and it was still pointing to rc1. So i must have done something wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong, the updates are not  pushed out to npm (where you download them from). That process can take some time depending upon whether the CLI is ready to be released or not.

Comment: @Brocco ah right thanks, I get it. It's just annoying that all these steps/tools each have to be updated in order to make it work. But I get it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes a bit late, but for other people needing this. You need the `--next` flag of the Angular CLI:

> $ ng update --help
> --next
> Use the prerelease version, including beta and RCs.

Like this, which should be able to find versions like `14.0.0-rc.1`:

```
ng update --next @angular/core @angular/cli
```

If you don't include the `--next` flag and try to specify the version directly, you'll get errors like:

```
$ ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14
An unhandled exception occurred: No matching version found for @angular/cli@14.
```

Comment: Six+ years later and no longer (only) in rc, but i guess it's still valuable information :)